# Prehistoric fossils

Tags: anatomy, species-identification

I have found very old seashell fossils (clamps) on a hill. They may be as old as a million years. Who can tell me how old they may be looking the pictures shown.

Comment: Hi @gio ! Welcome to Biology S.E. Could you please attach the pictures you mention in your question.

Comment: Fossils are dated in several ways. Radiometric dating, which we cannot do over the internet and if you're asking on the internet then you can't do it either. Identifying the fossil's species, which allows you to have a range of when the fossil could have been from insofar as other, better-dated discoveries of fossils in that species tell us when that species existed, and finally identifying the geological layer the fossil was found in. In other words, you should give a picture of the fossil so people can find the species and say exactly where you found it and what the surrounding area was like

Comment: Also the location where you found it.  If it comes from an undisturbed rock layer, that would help pin down a date.  Though perhaps not: the area I grew up in (upstate New York) had a good many rocks with fossil shells that were glacial erratics from the last Ice Age.